# Forwarding formControlName to inner component in Angular with Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have one custom control component `<some-input>` that i wrapped to `<ext-some-input>`. **SomeInput** is encapsulated, has own API and supports reactive forms.
**ExtSomeInput** is created as high-level wrapper over **SomeInput**.

I have following html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <ext-some-input formControlName="name">
</form>
```

and **ExtSomeInput**'s html:

```
<some-input formControlName="_???_"></some-input>
```

The question is how to forward **formControlName** to inner **SomeInput** component? I need to tie the form and inner formControl up. Is this possible?

EDITED:

I've created stackblitz project with this issue: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-tie-reactive-forms-throgh-wrapper?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Your inner component can take `@Input` `controlName` but it won't work out of the box:

> Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.

In order to tie your control with parent FormGroup you can define `viewProvider` as follows:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
...
import { ControlContainer, FormGroupDirective } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  ...
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useExisting: FormGroupDirective
    }
  ]
})
export class DateWrapperComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() controlName: string;
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-tie-reactive-forms-throgh-wrapper-andd8w?file=src/app/date-wrapper/date-wrapper.component.ts)**

In case you don't know which exactly directive is provided as a `ControlContainer`(`FormGroupDirective`, `FormGroupName` or `FormArrayName`) you can use more generic approach:

```
viewProviders: [
  {
    provide: ControlContainer,
    useFactory: (container: ControlContainer) => container,
    deps: [[new SkipSelf(), ControlContainer]]
  }
]
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-tie-reactive-forms-throgh-wrapper-9csuwt?file=src/app/date-wrapper/date-wrapper.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you so much! It's absolutely what i need. I'll learn about `viewProviders` for a mandatory way

Comment: just want to note something for anyone who stumbles on this answer... It works but you'll get an error in console if you use formControlName as the input variable name. Just use a different input variable name for the intermediary component, like "controlName".

Comment: This seems to be working, but once you check the console you find the following error: `ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'someday'`. Please. Fix, otherwise other users would grap a buggy example.

Comment: @yurzui, is there a way to change the value of the `this.form.someday` inside the date-wrapper.component.ts file?

Comment: @yurzui How would you approach the same problem when using a **FormArray** too? I tried to implement your solution but get the **Cannot find control with name:** error. StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-tie-reactive-forms-throgh-wrapper-ajj7eg

Comment: @Víctor You should be using FormGroupName directive instead of FormGroupDirective. But there's another generic approach https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-tie-reactive-forms-throgh-wrapper-9csuwt?file=src/app/date-wrapper/date-wrapper.component.ts

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for the solution. One question, I want to check if the control is touched within the child component, how should I do it just using the controlName?

Answer (score 6):

I had almost same scenario and issues. My relieve came with this [article](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/component-architecture-reactive-forms-angular) by Todd Motto.

His approach is to give formGroup as parent to custom input component. Then, from this component, you can bind control (validator) and formControlName (value) to input tag.

As usually, example speaks more by himself.

> **Form component ts**

```
// Reactive Forms
form: FormGroup;    

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  // Form structure and validators
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    'user' : this.formBuilder.group({
      'username' : ['', Validators.required],
      'email' : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
    }),
    'identity' : this.formBuilder.group({
      'firstname' : ['', Validators.required],
      'lastname'  : ['', Validators.required],
      'address' : this.formBuilder.group({
        'street' : ['', Validators.required],
        'city'  : ['', Validators.required],
      })
    })
  });        
}

onSubmit() {
    // Get object with same structure as form but only with values
    console.log(this.form.value);
    alert('Form is ' + (this.form.invalid ? 'invalid' : 'valid'));
}
```

> **Form component html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <form-text [formGroupParent]="form.get(['user'])"
               [formGroupControlName]="'username'">
    </form-text>
    <form-text [formGroupParent]="form.get(['user'])"
               [formGroupControlName]="'email'">
    </form-text>
    <hr>
    <form-text [formGroupParent]="form.get(['identity'])"
               [formGroupControlName]="'firstname'">
    </form-text>
    <form-text [formGroupParent]="form.get(['identity'])"
               [formGroupControlName]="'lastname'">
    </form-text>
    <hr>
    <form-text [formGroupParent]="form.get(['identity','address'])"
               [formGroupControlName]="'street'">
    </form-text>
    <form-text [formGroupParent]="form.get(['identity','address'])"
               [formGroupControlName]="'city'">
    </form-text>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> **Custom input component ts (form-text)**

```
// Needed to bind formControlName
@Input() formGroupParent: FormGroup;
@Input() formGroupControlName: string;
// FormControl store validators
control: FormControl;

ngOnInit() {
    // Fetch Form control (validator) from FormGroup parent
    this.control = <FormControl>this.formGroupParent.get(this.formGroupControlName);
}
```

> **Custom input component html (form-text)**

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="formGroupParent">
  <label>{{formGroupControlName}}</label> 
  <input type="text" formControlName="{{formGroupControlName}}">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've run into a similar scenario where I did not want to pass formControlName to the wrapper component. My preferred way to solve this is to just reuse the formGroup passed from the parent form in the wrapper component. You can do this by injecting ControlContainer in the constructor of ExtSomeInput component:

#### ParentForm.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <ext-some-input controlName="name">
</form>
```

#### ExtSomeInput.component.ts

```
// pass the formControlName as string to wrapper
@Input public controlName: string;
public form: FormGroup;

constructor(public controlContainer: ControlContainer) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = <FormGroup>this.controlContainer.control;
}
```

#### ExtSomeInput.component.html

```
// use ng-container to omit this from the DOM
<ng-container [formGroup]="form">
  // wrapper markup here
  <some-input [formControlName]="controlName"></some-input>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can create a @Input in component `ext-some-input`

### ext-some-input.ts

```
@Input 
formControlName
```

### ext-some-input.html

```
<some-input [formControlName]="formControlName"></some-input>
```

Comment: This produces in the following error for me: `No value accessor for form control with name: '...'`

Answer (score 0):

Hey making a second answer here because we came up at work with a generic approach that we released as an open source library =).

You can find it here: https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form

It should help you manage:
- nested forms
- forms with polymorphic data
- better typings

Everything is explained into the readme and a complete example is provided into the /src folder. (lib is actually in projects/ngx-sub-form).

Live demo available here too: https://cloudnc.github.io/ngx-sub-form

Answer (score -1):

I think that you're actually looking something a bit more complex than an `input`.

If you want to create a customized input you can create a class which is going to be a `ControlValueAccessor` (custom form control).

Please check the following article where it's really well explained:

https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control

Comment: but `<some-input>` already supports reactive forms. Should i implement extra-bridge (ControlValueAccessor) between the form and `SomeInput` to get them working together?

Comment: I think that it'd be the right thing to do but can you make a small repro eventually on stackblitz? That'd be easier to help

Comment: I've created stackblitz project with this issue: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-tie-reactive-forms-throgh-wrapper?file=src/app/app.component.html)