# There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name:

Tags: angular

I have the following form initialisation code:

```
this.saleForm = this.formBuilder.group({

  montant:['',Validators.required],
  codeBarre:['',Validators.required],
  nomClient:['',Validators.required],
  prenomClient:['',Validators.required],
  adresseClient:[],
  telephoneClient:['',Validators.required]
});
```

and the template is:

```
<form [formGroup]="saleForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(saleForm)" novalidate>
        <tc-form-group>
          <tc-input   [placeholder]="'Code barre'" [type]="'number'" formControlName="codeBarre"></tc-input>
          <tc-form-description
          [tcColor]="'#e24d4d'"
          *ngIf="saleForm.controls.codeBarre?.touched && saleForm.controls.codeBarre.invalid">
          Le nom est obligatoire
        </tc-form-description>
        </tc-form-group>
```

but i'm getting the error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: ...

Comment: Its because you are using the separate component for formcontrolName, you need to implement `ControlValueAccessor` for your component  in order to use it:https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661430/angular-2-formcontrolname-inside-component

Comment: and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893088/forwarding-formcontrolname-to-inner-component-in-angular

Comment: @PrashantPimpale thanks, but i found out there was another method in the ts file that was initializing the form wrong. I was able to solve this issue by removing that method