# Using `formGroupName` when not nested object

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, formgroups

I have a form generated automatically with many fields according to a given declaration object.
The `formGroup` is also generated dynamically - Everything is working just fine.

I'm facing a problem with the nested objects. I've added the `formGroupName` attribute and set it accordingly to the declarations object. When the field is not nested then this attribute value is undefined.

My problem is the moment I'm adding the `formGroupName` attribute it is considered as nested (It does not matter what value I set it) and it is searching that value field in the `FormGroup` and crashes for non nested fields (Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute).

Is there a way to use this attribute (`formGroupName`) when nested and not nested, setting its value to something that will be considered as not nested or ignored ?

I've tried to write a short code showing my problem.

```js
const declarations = [
{ name: 'id' },
{ name: 'id', parentName: "relatedObject" },
];

const formGroupMembers = {};
declarations.forEach(dec => {
  if (dec.parentName){
    formGroupMembers[dec.parentName] = this.formBuilder.group({[dec.name] : []});
  }
  else{
    formGroupMembers[dec.name] = []
  }
});
this.formBuilder.group(formGroupMembers);
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <mat-form-field *ngFor="let dec of declarations" formGroupName="{{dec.parentName}}">
    <input matInput type="number" formControlName="{{dec.name}}">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**WORKAROUND**

Since i didn't find a solution to my problem, I've created a sub component with my field code. But then, there was a problem with the `FormGroup` & `formGroupName` that are declared in the parent component.. After doing some research online found a solution to that problem as well

Here the snippet of the solution.

This is the form/parent component that contains the fields components

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div *ngFor="let dec of declarations">
    <div *ngIf="dec.parentName" [formGroupName]="dec.parentName">
      <my-field [field]="dec"> </my-field>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!dec.parentName">
      <my-field [field]="dec"> </my-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the field component.

Note that the `viewProviders` section which makes the field component part of the form group in the parent component. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52926319/2410260).

```js
import { Component, Input, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-field',
  templateUrl: './my-field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-field.component.scss'],
  
  /////////////////// THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT /////////////////
  viewProviders: [ 
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useFactory: (container: ControlContainer) => container,
      deps: [[new SkipSelf(), ControlContainer]]
    }
  ]
  /////////////////// THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT /////////////////
})
export class MyFieldComponent {

  @Input() field: FieldDesc;
}
```

```html
 <input matInput type="number" [formControlName]="field.name" />
```